# Date change format in unix

Tags: shell-script, date

I am passing date as variable in function. I want to convert that date in different format.
Example

```
DT=2015-12-08
```

Want to convert `DT` to `08-dec-2015` in Unix.

Comment: Using what programming language?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming GNU date (i.e. non-embedded Linux):

```
$ LC_TIME=C date --date=2015-12-08 +%d-%b-%Y
08-Dec-2015
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a non-embedded Linux, or more generally a system with GNU date, you can use it to typeset an arbitrary date.

```
LC_ALL=C date -d "$DT" +%d-%b-%Y | tr A-Z a-z
```

If you don't have GNU date (or even if you do), you can do this in pure shell.

```
case $DT in
  *-01-*|*-1-*) month=jan;;
  *-02-*|*-2-*) month=feb;;
  *-03-*|*-3-*) month=mar;;
  *-04-*|*-4-*) month=apr;;
  *-05-*|*-5-*) month=may;;
  *-06-*|*-6-*) month=jun;;
  *-07-*|*-7-*) month=jul;;
  *-08-*|*-8-*) month=aug;;
  *-09-*|*-9-*) month=sep;;
  *-10-*) month=oct;;
  *-11-*) month=nov;;
  *-12-*) month=dec;;
esac
echo "${DT##*-}-$month-${DT%%-*}"
```